# Trying to Line Break Button and Item

Tags: javascript, css

Here is the code I am using (http://jsbin.com/ESOdELU/1/edit) -

```
var wordRandomizer = {
run : function(targetElem) {
var markup = this.createMarkup();
targetElem.appendChild(markup);
},
createMarkup : function() {
var that = this;
var frag = document.createDocumentFragment();

this.elem = document.createElement('span');

var button = document.createElement('button');
button.innerText = 'Change Item';
button.addEventListener('click', function() {
  that.changeItem();
});

frag.appendChild(this.elem);
frag.appendChild(button);

return frag;
},
changeItem : function() {
var rand = this.getRandInt(1, this.items.length) - 1;
console.log(rand);
this.elem.innerText = this.items[rand];
},
getRandInt : function(min, max) {
return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min;
},
items : [
'itemA',
'itemB',
'itemC',
'itemD'
]
};

wordRandomizer.run(document.body);
```

I want to be able to generate the items below the button opposed to beside it. How can I do this? As a bonus I would also like to know how I can format the font of the items without having to edit each item.

Comment: Is this what you want? http://jsbin.com/ESOdELU/6/edit

Comment: @Rhyono It works great on the link you provided with the added one line of code but when I add it to my script it still puts the item to the left of the button unfortunately.

Comment: Also, what is the max amount of items I can add to the code, I just added around 200 and I had to remove some for the script to work on my website. Is there a limit?

Comment: You had it as span, button. I changed it to button, line break, span. Make sure you copied all of my code exactly. 200 doesn't sound that high, so I'm not sure what went wrong there. You're sure you didn't leave off any apostrophes or commas?

Comment: Yes it is working fine now, thank you so much! I forgot to add the frag.appendChild(br); in because I couldn't just copy and paste all as I have already customised my own version of the script. I just need 1 more thing now, to be able to change the font (colour etc) of the items, can this be done relatively easy also?

Comment: I believe my answer incorporated everything you needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's your code with all of the changes you asked for: http://jsbin.com/ESOdELU/8/edit

```
var wordRandomizer = {
  run : function(targetElem) {
    var markup = this.createMarkup();
    targetElem.appendChild(markup);
  },
  createMarkup : function() {
    var that = this;
    var frag = document.createDocumentFragment();

    this.elem = document.createElement('span');
    this.elem.style.color = "blue";

    var button = document.createElement('button');
    var br = document.createElement("br");
    button.innerText = 'Change Item';
    button.addEventListener('click', function() {
      that.changeItem();
    });

    frag.appendChild(button);
    frag.appendChild(br);
    frag.appendChild(this.elem);    

    return frag;
  },
  changeItem : function() {
    var rand = this.getRandInt(1, this.items.length) - 1;
    console.log(rand);
    this.elem.innerText = this.items[rand];
  },
  getRandInt : function(min, max) {
    return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min;
  },
  items : [
    'itemA',
    'itemB',
    'itemC',
    'itemD'
  ]
};

wordRandomizer.run(document.body);
```

You can either use a class on the span, or if you want to continue to contain it fully in JS, build on the example I gave you there with the blue font color.

Answer (score 0):

you have few options for getting the line below the button.
You can swap the span to a div,and add the button before the span

```
frag.appendChild(button);
frag.appendChild(this.elem);
```

another option is to change your html and add a line break or give the span a display: block property.

if you really don't want to swap the order that you are adding the button and element to the DOM, you can use position to move them around. http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_positioning.asp

so for example you can add this css

```
span : {
     display : block;
     font-family : // list of fonts ;
}
```